# How to load data from SQLite without knowing its format

Tags: sqlite, haskell, sqlite-simple

I'm trying to load data from a SQLite database, but I can't know the data format, since it's user provided.

This works if all columns are of the same type:

```hs
(entries :: [[Text]]) <- query_ connection "select * from users"
```

But what can I do if the columns have different types (e.g. INTEGER or REAL)?

Comment: Try with `entries :: [[SQLData]]`. That type seems to represent the unconverted raw sqlite values, so conversion should never fail with it. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-0.4.18.0/docs/Database-SQLite-Simple.html

Comment: @danidiaz Thanks! How about you make this a proper answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Use `entries :: [[SQLData]]`

---

You seem to be using [sqlite-simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple). In that package, the type of [`query_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-0.4.18.0/docs/Database-SQLite-Simple.html#v:query_) is

```
query_ :: FromRow r => Connection -> Query -> IO [r]
```

`query_` uses the [`FromRow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-0.4.18.0/docs/Database-SQLite-Simple.html#t:FromRow) and (indirectly) [`FromField`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-0.4.18.0/docs/Database-SQLite-Simple-FromField.html#t:FromField) typeclasses. These are  helpers that transform incoming sqlite row and column data to the format expected by the user.

However, these transformations might fail when the source and output types are not convertible.

The [`SQLData`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-0.4.18.0/docs/Database-SQLite-Simple.html#t:SQLData) represents the "raw" untransformed sqlite datatypes.  Converting a column value to `SQLData` is a no-op and never fails. And using `[SQLData]` for the rows never fails either, because lists can handle any number of columns (unlike, say, a `(SQLData,SQLData)` tuple).

Therefore, when dealing with unknown schemas, we can use `[SQLData]` as the row type and then pattern-match on the `SQLData` values to discover what are the actual sqlite types.